# F# Intellisense in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense

Autocomplete and intellisense is TERRIBLE for visual studio for mac. It will literally autocomplete random objects in the middle of strings and will not work at all when in the middle of a function that doesn't have a valid return value yet (in for or let statements). I had to turn it off because it's way worse than being useless. Anyone have any tips on how to fix this or should I change IDE's? Or is this a problem unique to myself. For reference I am in a script file.

Comment: Hi Zachary Schwatz, could you please share the detail code that you typed in the script file and the actual result and expected result? Once I reproduce this issue, I will help you to report this issue to the VS for mac product team through Help-Send Feedback-Report a problem or in here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend Visual Studio Code with Ionide extension installed.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that for now. I won't mark as answer in the hopes someone knows of a way to fix these issues in VS for OSX.